# bundle of invalid errors: C2059, C2143, C2181, C2660

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

This bundle of errors is caused by one function, and none of these errors are valid

> ```
> error C2059: syntax error : '='
> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
> error C2181: illegal else without matching if
> error C2660: 'Lexicon::convertOntology' : function does not take 0 arguments
> ```

```
string Lexicon::convertOntology(string input, int d, string out, string temp) // C2059; C2143
{
    if (in.length() == 0 && temp.length() == 0) {return out; //check for completed conversion //C2181
    } else {
        int r = 1;
        if (d == 1) r = 0; 
        if (in[0] == '.' || in[0] == '-' || in == "") { //found deliminator or end //C2059; C2143
            return convertOntology(in.substr(1), d, out+=vectorSearch(list, temp, 0, d, r), ""); //convert and check // C2143; C2660
        } else return convertOntology(in.substr(1), d, out, temp); //increment and check
    }
}
```

I did not place all the errors, they are repeated 14 times - it seems clear that these are not errors but is an issue with the compiler parsing the text; there is something upstream from this that is unmatched. I checked the previous function and checked the lines prior to where this function is called and found nothing.

How do I resolve these errors?

Comment: You probably need `std::string` instead of `string`, and/or didn't include `<string>`.

Comment: Well, for one thing, your parameter is named `input`, but you refer to `in` throughout the function.

Comment: It is all too common a mistake to overlook the code writer as the primary suspect of any compilation errors.  The proper order of suspects is:  programmer, included files, computer configuration, compiler.  Even then, uninstalling and re-installing the compiler is a prudent measure before possibly embarrassing yourself claiming the compiler is "wrong".

Comment: Can we see the code that calls `convertOntology` for the first time?

Comment: What are `d` and `r`? As a general rule, please give variables meaningful names to help other coders (such as us) understand your code better.

Comment: @FredOverflow, `d` is an argument and `r` is declared inside the `else`.

Comment: @hmjd lol I must be blind, probably due to sleep deprivation

Comment: @James_McNellis nailed it - 'in' is #defined by a macro in the class library so to solve that error, I renamed it 'input'. Thank you wallyk :) And, fredOverflow I will follow the school of thought regading meaningful names over the 'r' school; this function uses d as a switch to read vector column 0 and return column 1 or read column 1 and return 0. Thank you all for the quick help!

Comment: @wallyk - I did not think that the compiler was wrong in that respect but my intuition was that there was a stray '=' or '}' somewhere in the preceding code and I was looking for guidance on how to find this 'ghost' stray mark. But, it was simpler than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you reference `in` throughout your function although you pass a variable called `input`.

Secondly, you should also check this `in[0] == '.' || in[0] == '-' || in == ""` in another order, where you check for *an **empty** string first*. If the string *is* empty, your program will crash here when you try and access the first element `[0]`. Put `in == ""` first.

Thirdly, `list` isn't defined anywhere I can see, and it's being used here, `vectorSearch(list, temp, 0, d, r), "");`

Finally, **eww**. Please don't write c++ like that. ***IMHO*** there is nothing wrong with excusing brackets for one line if statements, but try and make everything readable so the next person doesn't want to *blow their brains out* trying to figure out what's going on.

```
string Lexicon::convertOntology(string input, int d, string out, string temp)
{
  if (input.length() == 0 && temp.length() == 0) 
    return out; 
  else 
  {
    int r = 1;
    if (d == 1) 
      r = 0; 
    if (input[0] == '.' || input[0] == '-' || input == "") 
      return convertOntology(input.substr(1), d, out+=vectorSearch(list, temp, 0, d, r), "");
    else 
      return convertOntology(input.substr(1), d, out, temp);
  }
}
```

Comment: Speaking of readability, the construct `return` ... `else` always makes me wonder if the programmer understands what `return` does.